# Converting quarterly time-series data into monthly data

Tags: r, excel, time-series, stata, data-conversion

I am trying to use a quarterly price deflator on monthly housing data. Can you please help me convert the quarterly data into monthly data? I looked into using the Cubic Spline Interpolation method in Stata but had no luck getting the do file to work. I have access to excel and R so those are an option for me to try. Thank you for your time.

```
Quarterly       CPI Deflator Data    
1999-04-01  79.891
1999-07-01  80.180
1999-10-01  80.547
2000-01-01  81.163
2000-04-01  81.623
2000-07-01  82.152
2000-10-01  82.593
2001-01-01  83.112
2001-04-01  83.699
2001-07-01  83.973
2001-10-01  84.227
2002-01-01  84.497
2002-04-01  84.812
2002-07-01  85.190
2002-10-01  85.651
2003-01-01  86.179
2003-04-01  86.455
2003-07-01  86.934
2003-10-01  87.346
2004-01-01  88.108
2004-04-01  88.875
2004-07-01  89.422
2004-10-01  90.049
2005-01-01  90.883
2005-04-01  91.543
2005-07-01  92.399
2005-10-01  93.100
2006-01-01  93.832
2006-04-01  94.587
2006-07-01  95.247
2006-10-01  95.580
2007-01-01  96.654
2007-04-01  97.194
2007-07-01  97.531
2007-10-01  97.956
2008-01-01  98.516
2008-04-01  98.995
2008-07-01  99.673
2008-10-01  99.815
2009-01-01  100.062
2009-04-01  99.895
2009-07-01  99.873
2009-10-01  100.169
2010-01-01  100.522
2010-04-01  100.968
2010-07-01  101.429
2010-10-01  101.949
2011-01-01  102.399
2011-04-01  103.145
2011-07-01  103.768
2011-10-01  103.917
2012-01-01  104.466
2012-04-01  104.943
2012-07-01  105.508
2012-10-01  105.935
2013-01-01  106.363
2013-04-01  106.623
2013-07-01  107.128
2013-10-01  107.589
2014-01-01  108.009
2014-04-01  108.606
2014-07-01  109.044
2014-10-01  109.067
2015-01-01  109.099
2015-04-01  109.650


    Monthly Data    Monthly datapoint
1999-01-01  76.841
1999-02-01  79.863
1999-03-01  81.245
1999-04-01  78.911
```

Comment: Do you have any data to share? Seems like an interesting question, but would benefit from some data to help visualize the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is very hard to help you with only a description of the problem. Users are glad to help you but you have to allow them to help you by providing a piece of you data (usually with `dput`) and/or a desired output and/or things you have tried so far.

Comment: Added the quarterly data for your review. Thanks.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: ok. you added the data but what do you want to do exactly? it is still obscure. Please do specify well.

Comment: @DavidArenburg My desired output is to convert the data from quarterly to monthly data per my original question. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't understand what values will `CPI Deflator Data` have. I would suggest you'll reduce your data to 8 rows or so and show your *exact* desired output.

Comment: I understand your question fine, however, I'm not sure it is possible. You could use something like a CAGR formula to "guess" the monthly rates, but this is only an approximation. Where is the data coming from? does it have Monthly data that it is converting into Q's?

Comment: Hi, the desired result I seek is the following: Monthly Data Monthly datapoint
'1999-01-01 xxx
1999-02-01 xxx
1999-03-01 xxx
1999-04-01 xxx
1999-05-01 xxx'

Comment: What are the `xxx`? Are you kidding me?

Comment: @DavidArenburg please scroll to the bottom of the original data to see the desired result. I know converting data from quarterly into monthly is more troublesome than visa versa. Thank you for your time. Regards

Comment: xxx is going to be the econometrically derived number. the xxx number will be a splicing of the quarterly data. I.e.: 1999 Q1=156 then I need to use a numeric calculation such as the Cubic Spline Interpolation which would be helpful.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact values for these 5 rows? are these are just the values divided by 3? I would suggest you make that edit fast before your question will be closed.

Comment: I have no observations yet for the monthly data because it has to be derived first. One way that's really simple but mathematically not as accurate is to say if Q1=100 then Month1,Month2,Month3=100. Was hoping for a more precise approach. Thanks

Comment: Try something like the following `library(data.table);
library(zoo);
setDT(df)[, Quarterly := as.Date(Quarterly)];
temp <- df[, .(Quarterly = seq.Date(min(Quarterly), max(Quarterly), by = "month"))];
setkey(df, Quarterly)[temp, na.approx(CPI.Deflator.Data)]` (assuming `df` is your data set)

Answer (score 4):

Using `Lines` shown at the end, read the input from `Lines` into a zoo object, `zd`, (or use `read.zoo("myfile.dat", header = TRUE)` to read it from a file). Then compute a sequence of `"yearmon"` class months, `tt`, for interpolation and use `na.spline` to interpolate.  (An alternative would be to use `na.approx` in place of `na.spline` if linear interpolation were desired.)

```
library(zoo)
zd <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
tt <- as.yearmon(seq(start(zd), end(zd), "month"))
zm <- na.spline(zd, as.yearmon, xout = tt)
```

We used this input:

```
Lines <- "Quarterly       CPI 
1999-04-01  79.891
1999-07-01  80.180
1999-10-01  80.547
2000-01-01  81.163
2000-04-01  81.623
2000-07-01  82.152
2000-10-01  82.593
2001-01-01  83.112
2001-04-01  83.699
2001-07-01  83.973
2001-10-01  84.227
2002-01-01  84.497
2002-04-01  84.812
2002-07-01  85.190
2002-10-01  85.651
2003-01-01  86.179
2003-04-01  86.455
2003-07-01  86.934
2003-10-01  87.346
2004-01-01  88.108
2004-04-01  88.875
2004-07-01  89.422
2004-10-01  90.049
2005-01-01  90.883
2005-04-01  91.543
2005-07-01  92.399
2005-10-01  93.100
2006-01-01  93.832
2006-04-01  94.587
2006-07-01  95.247
2006-10-01  95.580
2007-01-01  96.654
2007-04-01  97.194
2007-07-01  97.531
2007-10-01  97.956
2008-01-01  98.516
2008-04-01  98.995
2008-07-01  99.673
2008-10-01  99.815
2009-01-01  100.062
2009-04-01  99.895
2009-07-01  99.873
2009-10-01  100.169
2010-01-01  100.522
2010-04-01  100.968
2010-07-01  101.429
2010-10-01  101.949
2011-01-01  102.399
2011-04-01  103.145
2011-07-01  103.768
2011-10-01  103.917
2012-01-01  104.466
2012-04-01  104.943
2012-07-01  105.508
2012-10-01  105.935
2013-01-01  106.363
2013-04-01  106.623
2013-07-01  107.128
2013-10-01  107.589
2014-01-01  108.009
2014-04-01  108.606
2014-07-01  109.044
2014-10-01  109.067
2015-01-01  109.099
2015-04-01  109.650"
```

Comment: fantastic answer. Please note historic data should be interpolated linearly in most cases. Projected data you can spline or whatever curve construction method you fancy